# Populate jQuery array with contents of CSV using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, csv

I'd like to populate my `data` array with the contents of a CSV file using PHP.

My current code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($line); ?>;
document.write(data);
</script>
```

However, when I run this, I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => McDonalds
    [1] => Fast Food
    [2] => London
)
Array
(
    [0] => Marios
    [1] => Italian
    [2] => Manchester
)

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = false;
document.write(data);
</script>
```

I'm guessing the `$line` variable is my issue here.

---

My `food.csv` file:

```
McDonalds,Fast Food,London
Marios,Italian,Manchester
```

The plan is to incorporate the `data` array into something like the demo below:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1nj2wofp/)**

Comment: Take a look at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It is a php function that orders data into a `JavaScript Object Notation` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you print a line you override the previous one. Also you're using jsonencode with a nonarray I think thats why it gives you false, try this:

```
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
$allfile = [];
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  print_r($line);
  $allfile[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($allfile); ?>;
document.write(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Wow!! You're fast :-D `var data = [["McDonalds","Fast Food","London"],["Marios","Italian","Manchester"]];
document.write(data);` is my new output - it worked beautifully :-)

Comment: Have to wait 6 minutes before accepting your answer. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `print_r()` save each line into an array and `json_encode` that. For example;

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  $arr[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
document.write(data);
</script>
```